# Installed psensor, I am having a hard time identifiying which reading corresponds to my gpu

Tags: nvidia, temperature

Here is the output from psensor temp monitor. So can someone  please help me identify my gpu temp?

Specifications: Intel® Core i7-7700HQ NVIDIA GTX 1060 OS-Type: 64-bit

[image: psensor output]

Comment: The GeForce line? I mean, a GeForce is a graphics adapter, isn't it?

Comment: I never heard anyone refer to it as  agraphics adapter but sure, I will presume a graphics card == graphics adapter. But still which temp reading  in the picture is the gpu?

Comment: I would think the `GeForce GTX ... temp` line with the 44°C reading. I don't know what the percentages mean, though. The last line is probably your HDD.

Comment: Yes. According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_card) _"A video card (also called a display card, graphics card, display adapter or graphics adapter) is an expansion card ..."_

Comment: @PerlDuck *identify through elimination* answer below!  **:D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click on the psensor icon
- Choose <kbd>Sensor Preferences</kbd>
- In the window now showing up, go to the Graph tab:
  [image: psensor Graph tab]
- For everything showing up in the <kbd>Name</kbd> list, remove the `Draw sensor curve` *from all items except* `GEForce GTX 1060 temp` (in your case, I have a 1070)

#### GPU Temp identified!

(as it's the only line left)

## :-)

Comment: the only line left now is the Geforce GTX 1060 0 temp, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ahhh, _now_ I understand. @IsseNur didn't ask for the numbers on the right hand side of the picture (the legend) but asked for the line in the graph (left part). I agree, for _that_ part "which-is-which" is hard to answer.